# Can I concat ONLY one column within a larger SQL query OR transpose multiple rows into extra columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

This is for a vendor web application that is trying to generate information to put into an email and send it.

I've seen similar answers that use FOR XML PATH but that concats the whole return into a single line where I need a single line per item. I've also seen answers that use subqueries but that doesn't seem to work in this instance.

I have 2 tables; OrderItem OI that lists all items ever ordered, OrderItemProperties OIP that lists all the options any customer has made for all items (about 5 to 6 for every item). None of the properties are identified by property type in any way, the table just lists [ItemID, PropUID, PropValue] where PropUID are just sequential numbers.

So far what I have is:

```
SELECT OI.ItemID, OI.TotalPrice, OIP.PropValue
FROM OrderItemProperties OIP
JOIN OrderItem OI ON OI.ItemID = OIP.ItemID
WHERE OI.OrderID = 12345
AND (OIP.PropValue IN ('MSNISA', 'KHNISA') OR OIP.PropValue LIKE '<DateTime>%')
```

Unfortunately, the only parameter the software passes to the query is OI.OrderID. This should generate a row for each item the in customers order which is then passed to an xlst document using `<xsl:for-each select..>` but what (obviously!) I'm getting is

```
ItemID | TotalPrice | PropValue
555    | 9.99       | MSNISA
555    | 9.99       | <DateTime><Server>17/01/2020...
556    | 19.50      | KHNISA
556    | 19.50      | <DateTime><Server>18/01/2020...
```

What I'm trying to get to is:

```
ItemID | TotalPrice | PropValue
555    | 9.99       | MSNISA, <DateTime><Server>17/01/2020...
556    | 19.50      | KHNISA, <DateTime><Server>18/01/2020...
```

Or what would be even better:

```
ItemID | TotalPrice | PropValue[1] | PropValue[2]
555    | 9.99       | MSNISA       | <DateTime><Server>17/01/2020...
556    | 19.50      | KHNISA       | <DateTime><Server>18/01/2020...
```

The application I'm using only has a limited number of parameters that it passes to a query but it does allow me to create and declare variables within a query.

Any help is appreciated as I'm just piecing things together as I go at the moment!

Comment: Just to clarify, the 'for xml path' portion will still work to achieve the desired results if you couple it with a group by statement. Additionally, have you looked into using a pivot?

Comment: Thanks Sean. I'm having a look at using group with xml path but it's throwing errors at the moment so I guess I'm not combining them correctly, I'll look into that. Also, I've never head of pivot in relation to sql, only excel which isn't feasable in this instance.

Comment: SQL also has pivot functions that can be utilized, much like a spreadsheet! I've also updated my answer with a Fiddle so that you can see what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

I think aggregation does what you want:

```
SELECT OI.ItemID, OI.TotalPrice,
       MIN(OIP.PropValue), MAX(OIP.PropValue)
FROM OrderItemProperties OIP JOIN
     OrderItem OI
     ON OI.ItemID = OIP.ItemID
WHERE OI.OrderID = 12345 AND
      (OIP.PropValue IN ('MSNISA', 'KHNISA') OR OIP.PropValue LIKE '<DateTime>%')
GROUP BY OI.ItemID, OI.TotalPrice;
```

Comment: This did actually return everytthing on one line. I don't know how it works or it knows to group the time values in one column and the location values in another but it works.

Comment: Hi PZ01, this code assumes that there are two PropValue entries for an itemID when grouping by ItemID and TotalPrice. The result is that this code will work so long as the conditions don't change - that's why Gordon controls by only allowing the values you provided in the example. If there was a third row, say, 'ZZZZ_GARBAGE' that we couldn't easily filter out, it could cause issues.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you could utilize the STUFF() command as you originally theorized. I don't have sample data to test this against, might be slight syntax issues. [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/187c5c/1).

```
-- Casts XML back to varchar
SELECT    [oi].[itemid]
        , MAX([oi].[totalprice]) AS          "totalprice"
        , STUFF(
(
    SELECT ',' + [oip].[propvalue]
    FROM    [orderitemproperties] AS [oip]
    WHERE  [oip].[itemid] = [oi].[itemid] FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
).value
       ( '.', 'varchar(max)' ), 1, 1, '') AS "propvalue"
FROM orderitem AS oi
GROUP BY [oi].[itemid];
```

```
-- ORIGINAL QUERY - experiences issues with xml to varchar formatting
SELECT    [oi].[itemid]
        , MAX([oi].[totalprice]) as "TotalPrice"
        , STUFF(
(
    SELECT ',' + [oip].[propvalue]
    FROM    [orderitemproperties] AS [oip]
    WHERE  [oip].[itemid] = [oi].[itemid] FOR XML PATH('')
), 1, 1, '') as "PropValue"
FROM orderitem AS oi
GROUP BY [oi].[itemid];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work but it's ugly. Ideally you would have some sort of Property Key that would describe what the "MSNISA" vs "" values. I could provide a little better answer if you can post the schema of your OIP table.

```
SELECT [ItemID] = OI.ItemID, [TotalPrice] = OI.TotalPrice, [PropValue1] = OIP1.PropValue, [PropValue2] = OIP2.PropValue
FROM OrderItem OI
JOIN OrderItemProperties OIP1 on OIP1.ItemID = OI.ItemID AND OIP1.PropValue = 'MSNISA'
JOIN OrderItemProperties OIP2 on OIP2.ItemID = OI.ItemID AND OIP2.Propvalue like '<DateTime>%'
WHERE OI.OrderID = 12345
UNION
    SELECT [ItemID] = OI.ItemID, [TotalPrice] = OI.TotalPrice, [PropValue1] = OIP1.PropValue, [PropValue2] = OIP2.PropValue
FROM OrderItem OI
JOIN OrderItemProperties OIP1 on OIP1.ItemID = OI.ItemID AND OIP1.PropValue = 'KHNISA'
JOIN OrderItemProperties OIP2 on OIP2.ItemID = OI.ItemID AND OIP2.Propvalue like '<DateTime>%'
WHERE OI.OrderID = 12345
```

Comment: You're right in that it's be a trivial problem if there was a property key for OIP table that denoted which property each value is for. Unfortunately it doesn't. it just sequentially lists all values for an item with no way of knowing what property they are for apart from inference by what the value is. I believe this might have been an oversight by the software creators.